# split a list based on a condition in java using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I want something like following code but by using streams functions or something better

```
List<String> a;
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();

for (String item : a) {
    if (item.equals("something"))
        break;

    b.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Java 9 `takeWhile​(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`:

```
List<String> b = a.stream().takeWhile​(item -> !item.equals("something")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: or `int ix = a.indexOf("something"); List<String> b = ix < 0? a: a.subList(0, ix);`

Comment: thanks for your answer but actually I am using java 8 and  would like to know if it can be done using java 8 or not

Comment: @saharehsanpour I'm not sure

Answer (score -1):

```
b = a.stream().filter(item -> !item.equals("something")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This would filter **all** item not equal to "something", instead of **only** those found before the first "something".